# How to increase the record size in Kafka cluster topic

Tags: apache-kafka

By default the max record size of Kafka is 1000000 bytes (Around 95KB).

But I want to insert the a record of size 10 MB.

To increase the default record size:

1.Given following values in **server.properties**:

```
message.max.bytes=12000000
replica.fetch.max.bytes=13100000
max.message.bytes=10000000
```

2. Also added following values in **consumer.properties**

   fetch.message.max.bytes=12097152

Please help me to solve this in Kafka cluster.

Comment: Are server.properties and consumer.properties in the same folder?

Comment: Yes, server.properties and consumer.properties are in same folder.

Comment: Put both files in different folders and try.

Comment: With the same folder for server and consumer properties working for me now. But not able to see the data (which have more than 1 MB of size) in Kafka Tool. Please suggest me what to do to get the huge sized data in Kafka tool.